# How do I support my open-source product through a Stack Exchange site without sufficient reputation to add a tag

Tags: support, tags

I'm starting to get a lot of support questions on my open-source product. I'm answering them via email, but it's getting to be a pain. I'd like to direct folks to Stack Overflow where at least we can have a public history of questions and answers.

Unfortunately, I don't yet have the 1500 reputation needed to add a tag in SO. I'm at ~750. My guess is that I can get about 20 points an hour by answering questions, but unfortunately I really don't have the 40 hours required to get there right now.

What can I do here?

Comment: The standard tools (bug & issue tracker, mailing lists, ...) have a lot more useful features for supporting an open source product (patch submissions spring to mind). This usage scenario is not necesarilly a very good fit for SO imho.

Answer (score 4):

#### Regarding the tag creation:

A tag is created by using in on some question.

If there is already a question about your product on SO, anybody with enough reputation could just append the tag for you (and thereby, create it).

#### Regarding the general idea:

What kind of support questions are you talking about? I'm asking, because Stack Overflow is about software **development**. If the support questions are about the **usage** of your software, they would probably be off topic on Stack Overflow (but on topic on Super User), unless it is a product used **for** software development (grey area).

Also, while there's nothing wrong with redirecting your users to Stack Exchange for support, keep in mind that your users will have to follow certain guidelines, or their questions might wind up getting closed. Make sure to recommend reading the FAQ before posting questions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that SO should become the official help forum for your personal project, but it could be a worthy addition. If your project is getting very popular, why not create its own website/forum? Your contributors will prefer much more being on a website dedicated to what they're looking for, and it will give more visibility to your project as well.

If you really don't want to spend time answering or posting questions, I think you can still suggest edits, this should give you +2 per edits, (by the time you reach 1500 you should even have an additional badge). That may not be the most exciting way to get your reputation, but probably a little faster if that's really what you want.